# instancesRespondToSelector returning true when it shouldn't

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, nsstring, ios7

I'm writing an iOS application that is to be backwards compatible up to iOS 6.0.

In iOS 7, the `NSString` instance method `drawInRect:withAttributes:` replaced `drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:`. To determine which method to use, I have the following code:

```
if ([NSString instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(drawInRect:withAttributes:)]) {
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *textStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
        [textStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
        [textStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        [[self title] drawInRect:_textRect withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle}];
}
else {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        [[self title] drawInRect:_textRect withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
```

Since `drawInRect:withAttributes:` was introduced in iOS 7, `instancesRespondToSelector:` should return false when running on an earlier version of iOS. However, when testing this on a device running iOS 6.1, it returns true, and subsequently crashes when attempting to call `drawInRect:withAttributes:`. Does anyone have any idea what's happening, or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It will work if you test [[self title] respondsToSelector:@selector(drawInRect:withAttributes:)] instead of using method "instancesRespondToSelector". It has problems with categories and class-clusters.

Comment: Hmm, didn't seem to fix it. Still returns true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because a method wasn't part of the public API for a given release, doesn't mean that it didn't exist. My guess is that `-drawInRect:withAttributes:` was private API in iOS 6, then was promoted to public in iOS 7. You can test for some other condition that you know is only true on iOS 6 for your conditional here. e.g. `if (NSClassFromString(@"SomeiOS7OnlyClass") != Nil)`.

Comment: so the MACRO NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) in NSStringDrawing.h is supposed to do what??

Comment: Guess it's just Apple weirdness, then. Marking this answer as correct simply because it works, though the true answer is still a mystery.

Comment: @elio.d, the NS_AVAILABLE_IOS macro is merely a hint to the compiler to allow for (compile time) warnings depending on API usage, etc. It's also useful when you're reading the headers as documentation. It has nothing to do with runtime behavior.

Comment: @Kamaros, to be entirely honest, I was too lazy to get a development environment including the iOS 6.0 SDK set up to check this for sure just to answer your question, but it's easy enough to test. Build an app using the iOS 6 SDK, and perform the same test at runtime. If it returns YES, what I said is correct.

Comment: I thought Apple uses '_' as prefix for its private APIs.

Comment: @iVishal, yes, `_`-prefixed methods are private. However, just because a method is *not* prefixed with `_` doesn't mean it's public. Public methods are exposed in the (public) framework headers along with being documented. Apple often adds new private methods in one release then "promotes" them to being public when they're ready for public consumption in a later release.